# How to properly implement button combinations with STM32?

Tags: c, button, embedded, stm32

I want to interface some tactile push-buttons with STM32. Then based on a combination of button presses for a certain time period, I need different functions executed.

I know that using HAL_Delays will freeze the program and I don't want to do it. I suppose timers is the way to go. In that case what should I use as the time period. And should I poll for the timer counter? What's the standard and fault-free way to do this?

Comment: you should not poll for anything

Comment: @P__J__ Yeah, of course.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of possibilities but a simple method is to capture the time of teh button-down event, and compare that to the current time.

A hardware intensive method is to connect each button to an input capture timer.  The button down time will then be captured and the time it has been held is the current timer value minus the capture time.  Then your application can determine for each button that is down, how long it has been thus.

However, that method requires one timer-capture unit for each button.  A less expensive solution is to connect each button to a GPIO EXTI input and for each button capture the systick time on the button-down interrupt.

In either case the handling of the captured time is identical.

Pseudocode:

```
int downTime( int button_id ) 
{
    int down_time = 0 ;

    // If the button is down, report how long it has been down
    if( buttonDown( button_id ) )
    {
        down_time = buttonTimerNow( button_id ) - buttonTimerCapture( button_id ) ;
    }

    return down_time ;
}

bool pressed( int button_id )
{
    // The button is pressed, if it has been down for 
    // longer than the switch bounce time.
    return downTime( button_id ) > DEBOUNCE_TIME ;
}

bool combinationPressed()
{
    // Test for the required combination of currently 
    // simultaneously pressed buttons.
    return pressed( BUTTON_A ) && pressed( BUTTON_B ) ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use periodic interrupt as here:https://www.diymat.co.uk/arm-three-function-click-double-and-long-click-button-library-timer-interrupt-driven/